# Facebook share response after share post on facebook by API

Tags: facebook, response, share

We are trying to get response from facebook after successful share a feed on Facebook by add this API or Share.php page of facebook. But we are not getting any response from there.
Anyone can suggest how we will check feed share or not in facebook.

Comment: what response do you need exactly and what for?

Comment: i want some id or status to check feed shared or not.

Comment: yes, but what for exactly? what would you do with the information? this question is VERY important for good answer.

Comment: You don’t get that kind of feedback any more, because it was abused too much by spammers using it to _force_ people to share in exchange for access to content, give them “points” for it, or other behavior that was not allowed in the first place.